# FFMPEG Convert video from while adding left/right bars with a specific color

Tags: ffmpeg

I've gotten a bit stuck on a manipulation that I am trying to do.

I have a 1920×1080 video.

I'd like to resize it to 1920×886, while keeping its aspect ratio, so it should add bars to the left and right. I'd like to specify the HEX color code of the side bars (`#CFD3DA`).

I've combined several answers to compose the following command, but it is unfortunately broken:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=1920:886:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:886:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:#CFD3DA@1,setsar=1 output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

Was not too far!

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "scale=1920:886:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:886:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:#CFD3DA@1" output.mp4
```